# Somar registros separados por virgulas - PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, soma

No banco mysql eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que o campo coluna está no formato json. Tenho vários registros em um único campo. Preciso de um script para contar cada registro separado por virgula e somar e atribuir a uma variável. Neste caso a variável ficaria com o valor 6.

No código abaixo eu consigo a quantidade de registros por linha, mas não estou conseguindo realizar a soma.

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

$banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao,'movement');

mysqli_set_charset($conexao,'utf8');

$res = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT coluna FROM tabela");

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

      echo count(json_decode($r['coluna'], true));      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No while some os resultados e fora dele apresente o resultado:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

      $count += count(json_decode($r['coluna'], true));      
}        

 echo  $count;
```